# Is it possible to callback C/C++ function/code in a GLSL shader when conditions are met?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, callback

Is it possible to run C/C++ code from a GLSL shader? E.g. in fragment shader pixel X,Y is reached so call a C/C++ function then continue as normal. (Since the screen size is very small and functions will be very small as well, performance shouldn't be a huge issue.)

Comment: No, this is definitely not possible.

Comment: Why do you need this? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Borgleader I'm trying to do (simulated) h-blank raster effects.

Comment: I think this is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: How so? As far as I know, hblank triggers an interrupt on the SNES/Genesis.

Comment: @Accumulator: That's exactly how it is an XY problem. You're trying to do some kind of emulation stuff that OpenGL and shaders are ill-suited to handle.

Comment: So what should I do instead??

Comment: It might be good to explain in the question which problem you are actually trying to solve (in your case something with the hblank thing). Then a good answer could explain how to do this instead of just answering why it is impossible to have callbacks from shader code.

Comment: @Accumulator: It's an XY problem also, because the whole notion of "in fragment shader pixel X,Y is reached" does not make sense at all. There's no *specific* order in which fragments are processed and for all you know *every* fragment inside a primitive is processed simultanously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the GPU as an special machine that works only with GLSL programs.

But you can write that function (in GLSL language, not C/C++) and call it in the shader. If you are going to use in a fragment shader, then compile this function as a fragment shader too and link it to the program where you use it.

The calling shader must declare this function, otherwise it's ignored.

Comment: What about exiting the shader / rendering process entirely when the condition is met?

Comment: Once the shaders get in action, due to glDrawXXXX calls, you can not stop them. You can set a range of data to be processed, not all of them, but you can't exit/enter shaders at any point in the flow.

Comment: is there no way to draw "line by line," (scanlines) then?

Comment: Oh yes, you can send a glDraw for just one line and get some feedback. But having zillions (or just a few thousands) of lines draw calls is a counter perfomance issue.

Comment: My vertical height (number of lines) would be no more than 240. Though I'm not sure how I can actually draw textures and everything really "line by line."

Comment: In theory, it's possible to write a compiler that translates a subset of C++ to GLSL. Since GLSL doesn't have classes, you'd need to simulate them using structs.